# Cannot GET / express

Tags: express, stripe-payments

localhost:3000/ throws this error : Cannot GET / :
I do have an index.html file inside of my public folder, no matter what port i try and run on I always get Cannot GET / I've tried looking online but I cannot find a solution

```
 server.js
 require('dotenv').config()

const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static("public"))

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY)

const storeItems = new Map([
[1, { priceInCents: 10000, name: "Learn React Today"}],
[2, { priceInCents: 20000, name: "learn CSS Today"}],
])

app.listen(3000)


script.js
const buttom = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
console.log("Checkout")
})
```

Comment: You might be writing a wrong path in the `express.static("public")`. Try something like `path.join(__dirname,"../public")`

Comment: app.use(express.static("../public")) this works